# C# Windows Forms Generic Object

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, dropdown

Tenho uma aplicação Desktop em C# e preciso carregar um dropdown com uma opção "Todos" e o restante vindo de uma tabela do banco de dados. Para carregar o dropdownlist fiz algo assim:

```
        cmbOpcoes.Items.Add(new { Id = 0, Name = "Todos" });
        foreach (opcao o in db.opcao.OrderBy(c => c.nome).ToList())
        {
            cmbOpcoes.Items.Add(new { Id = opcao.id, Name = opcao.nome.ToString() });
        }
        cmbOpcoes.ValueMember = "Id";
        cmbOpcoes.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmbOpcoes.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

E até aí funciona bem! Ele carrega as opções e vem default com a opção "Todos" selecionada. O problema ocorre quando eu tenho pegar a opção preenchida pelo usuário. O tradicional:

```
cmbOpcoes.SelectedValue
```

vem com valor null. A opção:

```
cmbOpcoes.SelectedIndex
```

não vem null, mas ele não contém o ID e sim o índice do valor no dropdown. O mais próximo do que preciso foi o

```
cmbOpcoes.SelectedItem
```

Com o mouse sobre ele, vejo que tem um objeto { Id = "3", Name = "Opção X" }, porém eu não consigo acessar essas propriedades.

Qual o código para eu acessar esse Id, pois é dele que preciso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para acessar o conteúdo do `cmbOpcoes.SelectedItem`você tem que converter-lo para um objeto(Classe) que contém as propriedades, como os seus itens são anônimos, você pode utilizar o `dynamic` para acessar as propriedades.

Veja um exemplo:

```
dynamic obj=cmbOpcoes.SelectedItem;
int id=obj.Id
string name=obj.Name;
```

Comment: Excelente! Funcionou muito bem! Obrigado, Tiago!

Comment: @FelipeBulle Você pode escolher a resposta como "correta" clicando no ✓ embaixo das setas para votar.

Comment: Perfeito, marcada!

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx), você pode obter o índice com `SelectedIndex` mesmo e o texto da opção com `(SelectedItem as Object).ToString()`.

```
private void showSelectedButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    int selectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    Object selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    MessageBox.Show("Selected Item Text: " + selectedItem.ToString() + "\n" +
                    "Index: " + selectedIndex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, Daniel! Eu já via visto isso, mas realmente não funciona. O índice não é o ID. E o selectedItem.toString() traz o resultado que eu comentei na pergunta. Mas mesmo assim, obrigado!